# How does it internally work when a SOAP web-service is called?

Tags: java, web-services, soap

I am new to SOAP web services. I am learning it from Youtube videos on my own. I have a doubt that how web service internally works. 
I know(i might be wrong) there are overall of 3 steps :
1. A SOAP request is created at client end.
2. The SOAP request is sent over network through HTTP/UDP.
3. Server processes the SOAP request and sends back the SOAP response.

I think these 3 steps must be divided into sub-steps. So could anyone help me knowing what internally happens when a web service is invoked please.

Complete step from request generation to response received would be helpful.

As we know there is a standard question how hashmap works, if i can get the answer the same way then it will really be very helpful.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Basically you have described the flow. Please, be specific with your doubts. You can read yourself the standard [Using SOAP in HTTP](https://www.w3.org/TR/2000/NOTE-SOAP-20000508/#_Toc478383526)

Comment: The question is, what happens internally when a web service is invoked?